# Verilog: Sum over n register

Tags: sum, verilog

Im trying to build an moving average module. It should use the number of values to use as parameter.

How do I get the sum of all n `tmp`-registers using a `for`- or `gernerate`-block within one clock-cylce?

```
reg [WORDLEN - 1:0] tmp [SIZE - 1:0];
reg [WORDLEN + SIZE / 2 - 1:0] sum;
always @(posedge clk)
    sum <= sum(tmp) // Like <= tmp[0] + tmp[1] + ... + tmp[SIZE-1]
```

Comment: This technique is lowering the frequency of clock. You can use a `reset` input to reset `sum`, then the operation could be completed after some clock rising edges. In each clock just add one element of `tmp` with `sum`. (You can use a counter to count the required cycles for operation)

Answer (score 3):

Loops like this tend to be easier to understand if you first break apart the synchronous and combinatorial parts. First we have a combinatorial loop which unrolls to a configurable number of adds. Then imply a flip-flop on the result.

```
 integer i;
 reg [WORDLEN + SIZE / 2 - 1:0] sum_comb;
 always @* begin 
   sum_comb = 'd0;
   for( i=0; i< SIZE; i=i+1) begin
     sum_comb = sum_comb + tmp[i];
   end
 end

 always @(posedge clk) begin
   sum <= sum_comb;
 end
```

Comment: And if you want get more compact, you can use `sum_comb += tmp[i];`

Comment: I completed this code and could get the correct result in Modelsim, but when I synthesized it on ISE (Xilinx Synthesis Tool), the Technology schematic was a black box. Are you sure the code is synthesized to a specific hardware ?

Comment: @Amir I often synthesis code like this with out issue. Looking at sum_comb you can see that it is just a number of adders in parallel. Most tools should be able to see this and do sensible things.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SystemVerilog, you can just write:

```
always @(posedge clk)
    sum <= tmp.sum;
```

Below is a complete sample code:

```
module test;
    parameter WORDLEN = 8;
    parameter SIZE = 4;
    reg [WORDLEN - 1:0] tmp [SIZE - 1:0];
    reg [WORDLEN + SIZE / 2 - 1:0] sum;
    logic clk = 0;

    initial begin
        tmp = '{ '{1}, '{4}, '{6}, '{7}};
        forever begin
        clk = ~clk;
        #10;
        tmp [0] = tmp[0] + 1; //Increment tmp[0] twice during each clock for testing
        end
    end

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    sum <= tmp.sum ;
    $display ("sum(tmp) = sum(%p) = %d", tmp, sum)   ;
    end
endmodule
```

output:

```
# sum(tmp) = sum('{1, 4, 6, 7}) =   18
# sum(tmp) = sum('{1, 4, 6, 9}) =   20
# sum(tmp) = sum('{1, 4, 6, 11}) =   22
# sum(tmp) = sum('{1, 4, 6, 13}) =   24
# sum(tmp) = sum('{1, 4, 6, 15}) =   26
# sum(tmp) = sum('{1, 4, 6, 17}) =   28
```